# Rails 3 - nested select and ".last"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, chaining

I have a scenario which seems to be should be something addressed on the model side of things but can't figure out a combination of Activerecord methods that works. The relevant parts of my db are as below:

```
Part:
id
part_id
created_at
...

Parttest:
id
part_id
pass (boolean)
created_at
```

A Part can have many Parttests and a Parttest belongs to a single part (setup in the relevant models as has_many and belongs_to).

In it's life - a part can be tested many times and can pass, fail, pass etc. 
Using rails / activerecord I would like to retrieve the recordset of Parts where the last (most recent) Parttest is a pass. Earlier records of parttest should not be taken into consideration and are for historical use only.

I've tried nested selects without much success. I could always code the logic in the controller to check each Part object in Part.all.each and push those into an array but this doesn't feel like the right way to do it. All help much appreciated :)

Comment: If you found of the answers helpful, do you mind marking an accepted answer? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misread your post, you want to do something like this [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)

`Part.joins(:parttests).where(parttests: {pass: true})` will give you all parts who have passing tests

try `Part.joins(:parttests).last.where(parttests: {pass: true})`

Comment: Just an FYI... you can do `order(created_at: :desc)` instead of passing an explicit string. There's also a syntax error in your scope. It's missing a `,`--fixed.

Comment: @Mohamad - I've probably misunderstood your solution but it doesn't work. I can't call Part.parttests because parttests isn't a method of the Part class. Wouldn't the code above give me the parttest - rather than the part which has passed a test? (It's the parts I want, not the partttest)

Comment: @SG84 see my answer! This was marknach's answer not mine. I added my own.

Comment: Also this code has another syntax error now that the poster edited it. `Parts` is pluralised. It should be `Part`. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using a scope

```
class Parttest
  scope :passed_tests, -> { where(pass: true) }
end

@part       = Part.find(1)                      # Fetch part instance
@part_tests = @part.parttests.passed_tests.last # Fetch its tests
```

Or using a condition on the association:

```
class Part
  has_many :passed_tests, class_name: 'Parttest', -> { where(pass: true) }
end

@part_tests = @part.passed_tests.last
```

### Update

Now that I have understood the question correctly. How about this?

```
class Part
  has_many :passed_tests, class_name: 'Parttest', -> { where(pass: true) }
  scope :with_last_passed_test, -> { joins(:passed_tests).last }
end
Part.with_last_passed_test
```

Comment: I think OP wants to find Parts whose most recent Parttest passed - not the most recent passing Parttest for each post

Comment: That's correct - I only want to consider the most recent parttest.

Comment: @SG84 I've updated my answer. Give that a try. It should work.

Comment: @Mohamad - thanks for the help on this. Your last edit above looks right and I understand (I think) what it's supposed to do but I'm getting syntax errors for both lines within the class.
"syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>" for both lines so I guess it's unhappy about the new lambda syntax perhaps? I'm on Ruby 2 with rails 3.2.16

Comment: @SG84 You're welcome. I think on Rails 3.x you can't use this syntax. Try this instead: `has_many :passed_tests, ..., -> conditions: "pass = true"` - Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/association_basics.html

Comment: still no joy! I've implemented what @cschroed mentioned as a class method which returns all the failed parts.

    `def self.get_failed_parts
        @@failedparts = []
        Part.all.each do |p|
          if p.parttest.count > 0 && p.parttest.last.pass == false
            @@failedparts << p
          end
        end
        return @@failedparts
      end`

Answer (score 0):

I had originally posted a lengthy SQL query as one option, but that suggestion wasn't very clean so I've removed it.  Here is a way to break this down into a few small pieces.

Say we start with these Parttest rows:

```
id  part_id  created_at  pass
1   1        2014-04-26  true
2   1        2014-04-27  false
3   2        2014-04-26  false
4   2        2014-04-27  true
```

1) First, we want to find the most recent Parttest row for each Part.  We can do this with:

```
# Parttest model
def self.most_recent
  max_rows = select("part_id, MAX(created_at) as max_created_at").group(:part_id)
  joins("INNER JOIN (#{max_rows.to_sql}) AS max_rows
      ON parttests.part_id = max_rows.part_id
     AND parttests.created_at = max_rows.max_created_at")
end
```

The `select` will grab these values:

```
part_id  created_at
1        2014-04-27
2        2014-04-27
```

And the `join` will connect us back up with the other Parttest columns:

```
id  part_id  created_at  pass
2   1        2014-04-27  false
4   2        2014-04-27  true
```

2) Then we want to only keep the passing tests.  We can do this with:

```
# Parttest model
scope :passed, -> { where(pass: true) }
```

Combining this with (1), we can get the most recent tests only if they were passing tests by calling:

```
Parttest.most_recent.passed
```

This would only include return this row from our example:

```
id  part_id  created_at  pass
4   2        2014-04-27  true
```

3) Then to find all Parts where the most recent test was passing we can provide this scope:

```
# Part model
scope :most_recent_test_passed, -> { where("id IN (?)", PartTest.most_recent.passed.map(&:part_id)) }
```